# get multiple Elements By Tag Name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello there am trying to make an image gallery for example lets say that I have multiple images and I want to change their opacity when I hover over them by using JavaScript I know that this is possible with CSS but am trying to accomplish this with JavaScript I tried using get Elements By Tag Name method but the problem it just can access one element by time so can I do that thanks

Comment: can you show the code you tried?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of nodes, not one. Could you post the code you currently have that's causing you trouble?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to collect you image elements like

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

then you have to do like

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, e => e.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { do something}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (e) {
    // Here you can access each image individually as 'e'.
});
```

When you hover, get the ID of that image. Then loop through all images (example above) and set their opacity. If the element is equal to the one you clicked on (remember, you just took the ID so you can use it), just skip to the next one using `continue;`.

Comment: elements is a HTMLCollection you can not use array functions directly. You best do like Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, callback)

Comment: This does not work. `getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist, not an array. You can convert it to an array or use a for loop.

Comment: @Redu Fixed, thank you.